# vmlinuz and initrd not found after building the kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, initrd

After configuring and building the kernel using make, why don't I have `vmlinuz-<version>-default.img` and `initrd-<version>.img`, but only got a huge `vmlinux` binary (~150MB)?

Comment: Did you forget to run `make bzImage`? Also, did you make a monolithic kernel? Are you running a Debian-like OS? If so, and you're not cross-compiling, there are easier ways to build a kernel.

Comment: I compiled it in OpenSUSE (however, I downloaded the latest source from `kernel.org`). After `make menuconfig`, I typed `make` and let it does the job.

Comment: You need `make bzImage` to generate the bzImage kernel. Say `make help` to see some brief instructions. Check the Linux Kernel Howto for detailed instructions. If you answered every `make menuconfig` question with *Y* (rather than *M* where appropriate), you've tried to include *every* driver in the kernel proper. This is a very, very bad idea and the kernel won't boot because it's too large. The `initrd` image is generated by other tools.

Comment: I've just checked the config again. It seems I have not enabled loadable kernel module support. I thought it is default. I will try to compile again and will notify when it's done.

Comment: Lots of the comments above look like good answers to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compressed images are under `arch/xxx/boot/`, where `xxx` is the arch. For example, for `x86` and `amd64`, I've got a compressed image at `/usr/src/linux/arch/x86/boot/bzImage`, along with `/usr/src/linux/vmlinux`.

If you still don't have the image, check if `bzip2` is installed and working (but I guess if that were the problem, you'd get a descriptive error message, such as "bzip2 not found").

Also, the kernel config allows you to choose the compression method, so the actual file name and compression algorithm may differ if you changed that kernel setting.

As others already mentioned, initrds are *not* generated by the linux compilation process, but by other tools. Note that unless, for some reason, you need external files (e.g. you need modules or udev to identify or mount `/`), you don't need an initrd to boot.

Answer (score 4):

According to documentation:

http://tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/kernel-custom.html

When you do:

make bzImage

and then:

cp bzImage vmlinuz

to create the vmlinuz file.   Ie, they are the same file :-).